# Show for any measurable set E: m(E)= sup{ m(K): K $\subset$ E}, K compact

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need to prove that for any measurable set E one has m(E)= *sup* { m(K): K $\subset$ E}, where the supremum is taken over all compact subsets K of E and m(E) denotes the measure of the set E.

My idea is to show m(E) $\leq$ *sup*{ m(K): K $\subset$ E} and *sup*{ m(K): K $\subset$ E} $\leq$ m(E). I have shown that if E is measurable then for any $\epsilon$> 0 we can find a closed set F $\subset$ E such that m(F - E)< $\epsilon$. I have assumed m(E)< $\infty$. Now, if K is compact then it is closed (by the Heine-Borel theorem), so for any $\epsilon$>0 : m(E - F)< $\epsilon$ implies m(E) $\leq$ sup{m(F)}.

I think the inequality  *sup*{ m(K): K $\subset$ E} $\leq$ m(E) can be seen as a consequence of the sub-additivity of the measure (am I wrong?).

Note: We are working on $R^{n}$

Is this approach correct? I am new to measure theory so I'd love any criticisms and/or corrections. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should specify what space you are working on.

Comment: thanks, I just edited it.

Comment: The inequality $\sup\{m(K):K\subseteq E, K\mbox{ compact}\}\leqslant m(E)$ is a consequence of the fact that $m$ is monotone, so $K\subseteq E$ implies $m(K)\leqslant m(E)$, for all $K\subseteq E$ (especially, $K$ compact)

Comment: Regarding the first point. You are on the right track with proving that there is a closed $F\subseteq E$ such that $m(E-F)<\varepsilon$. I don't understand the last part: If $K$ is compact, then it is closed (correct), but "so for any $\varepsilon>0: m(E - F)<\varepsilon$  implies $m(E) ≤ \sup{m(F)}$", how does this follows from "$K$ compact"?

Comment: By $m$ you mean the Lebesgue measure right? This is easily not true in general. In this case, what you are asking is to show that the Lebesgue measure is inner regular, this can be found in most measure theory textbooks.

Answer (score 3):

**Lemma 1** If $E$ is a measurable set, then for all $\varepsilon>0$ exist a closed set $F$ that $F\subset E$ and $m(E-F)<\varepsilon$.

**Lemma 2** if $E_1\subset E_2\subset E_3\subset \dots$ is a sequence of measurable sets then $m\left( {\bigcup}_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}\right)=\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}m(E_{n})$.

For all $\varepsilon>0$ take a closed set F such that $m(E-F)<\varepsilon $ and $F\subset E$.
Consider the compact (measurable) sets $K_n=F\cap cl(B(0,n))$.

Then by lemma 2,  $m(K_n)\rightarrow m(F)$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$.

**1.** Suppose that $m(F)<\infty$.

So for big n, $m(F)<m(K_n)+\varepsilon$ and

$m(E)=m(F\cup (E-F))=m(F)+m(E-F)<m(K_n)+2\varepsilon$. Then

$$m(E)=\sup\{m(K):K\subset E, K\text{  compact} \}.$$

**2.** If $m(F)=\infty$.

Then $m(K_k)\rightarrow \infty$ and is clear that $\sup\{m(K):K\subset E, K\text{  compact} \}=\infty$.

On the other hand, $\infty=m(F)\le m(E)$.